# TYPO3 Backend broken

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-9.x

Okay, I have a weird problem and hope someone might know the solution:

Since yesterday the backend of a TYPO3 site I'm working on is broken. I can log in normally, but when I then select one of the functions in the left menu (no matter which one) this will happen and nothing will work any more afterward:

[image: broken typo3 backend]

Initially, there's just the second menu, the third one appeared when I tried clicking through all the functions in the hope this would change something.

Sometimes an error appears:

"Page tree error

Got an unexpected response from the server. Please check logs for details."

But of course, I can't access the logs...

Clearing the browser cache, restarting the browser in save mode without any plugins, log into another user account - nothing works, the result is always the same.

Does anyone have any idea how to get out of this again? Apparently other users still can work fine with the page, so it seems as it's not a general problem with the installation.

Comment: from the image it doesn't look that you have admin rights, i'd start cleaning up the cache online but ... you need to have admin rights, and then check if you have some broken extension ... what is your host?

Comment: Check the logs on the file system: var/logs/typo3_...; Also please some minimum of information: browser/PHP versions, which webserver are you running on? What changed because obviously something changed... I suspect php-fpm or webserver config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TYPO3 backend consists of a frame in the website. in your case you see the website repeated in the frame twice.

Normaly that is a sign for broken session handling as the frame tries to build the basic backend.
Sometimes the browsers mix it up (so the information about your browser is helpful), sometimes the web server become confused.

Try to clear all browser caches.
Try different browser.
Reset all TYPO3 caches and verify all session data can be stored. If needed use the InstallTool instead of TYPO3 backend.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You're correct, it was the session saved in the browser I used. But deleting the cache alone wasn't enough - I also had to delete the session cookie set by Typo3 - that was the final culprit! :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the culprit when I thought about why clearing the cache didn't help while the same browser on another computer worked fine: What remains, when the cache is cleared?

Cookies.

The broken session was saved in a Cookie apparently, and deleting the cookies solved the problem immediately. :)